# How to express and graph this function in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Hello I want to consider this integral as the function of r
V(r)= integrate[(r(Sqrt[16-x^2])-1/2r^2sin(2/rSqrt[16-x^2])),{x,-4,4}]
then I want to graph V(r) and V'(r) how to express this value on mathematica to graph the function V(r),V'(r)?

Image about V(r) is below here.  Thank you
[image]

Here's What I have done and didn't work
[image]

Comment: Please show us what have you already tried.

Comment: `Integrate` cannot evaluate `Integrate[Sin[Sqrt[16 - x^2]], {x, -4, 4}]`.  In addition, the error messages suggest that you may already have given values to some variables used in the integral.

Comment: `NIntegrate` will give a numerical answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, It is very useful. I learnd a lot from all of you guys. (Quite complicated than I expected) Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int_{-4}^4 \left(r \sqrt{16-x^2}-\frac{1}{2} r^2 \sin \left(\frac{2 \sqrt{16-x^2}}{r}\right)\right) \, dx=\\\int_{-4}^4 r \sqrt{16-x^2} \, dx-\int_{-4}^4 \frac{1}{2}
   r^2 \sin \left(\frac{2 \sqrt{16-x^2}}{r}\right) \, dx$$

Mathematica have problems to compute second define integral.

We use a`MellinTransfrom` as workaround.

```
V[r] = Integrate[r*Sqrt[16 - x^2], {x, -4, 4}] -
(InverseMellinTransform[Integrate[MellinTransform[1/2 r^2 Sin[A/r*Sqrt[16 - x^2]], A, s], 
{x, -4, 4}, Assumptions -> Re[s] < 2], s, A] /. A -> 2) //Simplify // Expand

(*8 π r - 2 π r^2 BesselJ[1, 8/r]*)

D[V[r], r] // FullSimplify

(*2 π (4 + 8 BesselJ[0, 8/r] - 3 r BesselJ[1, 8/r])*)

Plot[{Evaluate@V[r], Evaluate@D[V[r], r]}, {r, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"V[r]", "V'[r]"}]
```

[image]

Asymptotic:

```
ATINF = Asymptotic[V[r], {r, Infinity, 3}]
(*-((512 π)/(3 r^3)) + (64 π)/r*)

ATZERO = Asymptotic[V[r], {r, 0, 3}, Assumptions -> r > 0]
(*8 π r + Sqrt[π] r^(5/2) Cos[π]/4 + 8/r]*)

Plot[{Evaluate@V[r], ATINF, ATZERO}, {r, 0, 30}, 
PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 80}}, 
PlotLegends -> {"V[r]", "Asymptotic at Infinity", 
"Asymptotic at zero"}]
```

Comment: Both `MellinTransform` and `InverseMellinTransform` are defined as improper integrals and `MellinTransform[1/2 r^2 Sin[A/r*Sqrt[16 - x^2]], A, s]` results in `1/2 r^2 (Sqrt[16 - x^2]/r)^-s Gamma[s] Sin[(\[Pi] s)/2]`. If we use the definition of `MellinTransform`, then `Integrate[A^(s - 1)*1/2 r^2 Sin[A/r*Sqrt[16 - x^2]], {A, 0, Infinity}]` results in `ConditionalExpression[(
 r^2 ((16 - x^2)/r^2)^(-s/2) Gamma[s] Sqrt[Sign[16 - x^2]]
   Sin[(\[Pi] s)/2])/(2 Sign[r]), 
 Sqrt[16 - x^2]/r \[Element] Reals && -1 < Re[s] < 1]`. but you assume `Re[s] < 2`.   `InverseMellin` needs in justification.

Comment: @user64494 .Mathematica assume **not** me, try: `Integrate[
 MellinTransform[1/2 r^2 Sin[A/r*Sqrt[16 - x^2]], A, s], {x, -4, 4}]`

Comment: @MariuszIwanyuk:  Are you serious? I repeat, that making use of the definition of `MellinTransform` we obtain `ConditionalExpression[]` with `Re[s]<2` for `MellinTransform[1/2 r^2 Sin[A/r*Sqrt[16 - x^2]], A, s]`. Your comment is off-topic.

Comment: @user64494. If I use: `-1 < Re[s] < 1` or `Re[s]<2` Mathematica give me the same answer,so I don't know what your comments are for? I use **New age math** not **traditional**.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, It is very useful. I learnd a lot from all of you guys. (Quite complicated than I expected) Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Get closed form anylytical expression for V[r] with variable transformation `(2 Sqrt[16 - x^2])/r -> wx`

Integrand is symmetrical, therefore two times integral form 0 to 4. Numerical integral for comparison.

```
igd = r Sqrt[16 - x^2] - r^2/2 Sin [2/r Sqrt[16 - x^2]];

igd == (igd /. x -> -x)   (*   True   *)

nV[r_] := 
 NIntegrate[igd, {x, -4, 4}, MaxRecursion -> 50, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]

Solve[0 < x < 4 && r > 0 && (2 Sqrt[16 - x^2])/r == wx, x, Reals]

(*   {{x -> ConditionalExpression[1/2 Sqrt[64 - r^2 wx^2], 
    wx > 0 && 0 < r < 8/wx]}}   *)

dxdwx = D[1/2 Sqrt[64 - r^2 wx^2], wx]

(*   -((r^2 wx)/(2 Sqrt[64 - r^2 wx^2]))   *)

igd2 = (igd /. x -> 1/2 Sqrt[64 - r^2 wx^2] ) dxdwx // 
  Simplify[#, wx > 0 && r > 0] &

(*   (r^4 wx (-wx + Sin[wx]))/(4 Sqrt[64 - r^2 wx^2])   *)

{(2 Sqrt[16 - x^2])/r /. x -> 0, (2 Sqrt[16 - x^2])/r /. x -> 4}

(*   {8/r, 0}   *)

V[r_] = 2 Integrate[igd2, {wx, 8/r, 0}, Assumptions -> r > 0]

(*   2 \[Pi] r (4 - r BesselJ[1, 8/r])   *)

Plot[{nV[r], V[r], V'[r]}, {r, 0, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, {Opacity[.3], Thickness[.02], Red}, Blue}]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][
  r Sqrt[16 - x^2] - r^2/2 Sin[2/r Sqrt[16 - x^2]], {x, -4, 4}], w, 
 w == (2 Sqrt[16 - x^2])/r/x]` ?

Comment: If I am not mistaken,  this results in `0`, demonstrating a bug in `IntegrateChangeVariables`. `IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][
  r Sqrt[16 - x^2] - r^2/2 Sin[2/r Sqrt[16 - x^2]], {x, 0, 4}], w, 
 w == (2 Sqrt[16 - x^2])/r/x]` returns the input.

Comment: +1. Nice and quite natural way.

Comment: Thanks. (Didn't try IntegrateChangeVariables, have it not yet available. Didn't look for it either in the cloud. Anyway, seems better to wait until bugs are repaired. )

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, It is very useful. I learnd a lot from all of you guys. (Quite complicated than I expected) Thank you. !!

Answer (score 3):

I have strong doubts about a closed-form expression for `V[r]`, so we apply numeric integration by

```
V[r_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[r*Sqrt[16 - x^2]-1/2 r^2 Sin[2/r*Sqrt[16 - x^2]], {x, -4, 4}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5]
```

There exists a simple asymptotic of the integrand as `r` approaches infinity

```
Series[r*Sqrt[16 - x^2] - 1/2 r^2 Sin[2/r*Sqrt[16 - x^2]], {r,Infinity, 1}, Assumptions -> x >= -4 && x <= 4]
```

> $\frac{2 \left(16-x^2\right)^{3/2}}{3 r}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)^2\right)$

which implies the asymptotic of the integral and the `AsymptoticIntegrate` command catches it:

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[r*Sqrt[16 - x^2] - 1/2 r^2 Sin[2/r*Sqrt[16 - x^2]], {x, -4, 4}, 
 r -> Infinity]
```

> `(64 \[Pi])/r`

Finally,

```
Plot[{V[r], (64 \[Pi])/r}, {r, 0, 30}]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the question about `V'[r]`. Its plot can be obtained by the differentiation of the integrand wrt `r`: `DV[r_?NumericQ] :=   NIntegrate[   Sqrt[16 - x^2] + Sqrt[16 - x^2] Cos[(2 Sqrt[16 - x^2])/r] -     r Sin[(2 Sqrt[16 - x^2])/r], {x, -4, 4}, AccuracyGoal -> 5,    PrecisionGoal -> 5];Plot[Evaluate[DV[r]], {r, 0, 5}] `(`D[r*Sqrt[16 - x^2] - 1/2 r^2 Sin[2/r*Sqrt[16 - x^2]], r]` results in the integrand.) . More accurate plot needs in options.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, It is very useful. I learnd a lot from all of you guys. (Quite complicated than I expected) Thank you.  !!